# Javascript for loop is done at the beginning

Tags: javascript

why my loop isn't working? This loop is making all at the start. I get json in HamtaPokemon function and i get from z =11.

```
    console.log(z);
    for( var z=1; z<11; z++){
    console.log(z);

    var pokeid=$("#pokeid").val();
    HamtaPokemon(z).then((data)=>{
        console.dir(data);
        $("h1").text(data.name);
            var pokId = "pokId" + z;
            var pokName = "pokName" + z;

            var pokImage = "pokImage" + z;
            (pokId).toString() ;
            (pokName).toString(); 
            (pokImage).toString() ;
            console.log(z);
        //document.getElementById('pokId').innerHTML = data.id;
    //document.getElementById('pokName').innerHTML = data.name;
    //document.getElementById("pokImage").innerHTML= '<img src=http://img.pokemondb.net/artwork/'+data.name+'.jpg>';


        $("h4").text(data.id);


    });
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/433sd.jpg)

Comment: You want to apply a function (`HamtaPokemon.then(...)`) to each item in a list?

Comment: exactly, for each item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a utility function that chains the promises.

eg.

```js
function asyncForEach(items, cb) {
    return items.reduce((p,c) => {
        return p.then(value => cb(c));
    }, Promise.resolve());
}

var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];

function HamtaPokemon(z) {
    console.log(z);
    return Promise.resolve(z);
}

function cb(z) {
    return HamtaPokemon(z)
        .then(data => { /* ... */});
}

asyncForEach(items, cb)
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

The above could be modified to run them concurrently too. But I assumed sequential processing.

You also need to read about [asynchronicity in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).